# Text.Tabular.Table type errors - what is the type system asking from me?

Tags: haskell, formatting

I have the following code, using [this tabulation library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tabular):

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude, OverloadedStrings #-}

import ClassyPrelude
import qualified Text.Tabular as T

data Category = Age | Gender | Usual | Years
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Enum, Bounded)

 tabulate :: Text -> [[Int]] -> T.Table (T.Header Int) (T.Header Text) Int
 tabulate lbl tab = T.Table (T.Group T.NoLine (map T.Header leftcoll)) (T.Group T.DoubleLine [T.Header lbl, T.Header "All", T.Header "Cluster0", T.Header "Cluster1"]) rest
   where leftcoll = map (`indexEx` 0) tab
         rest = map (drop 1) tab
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following errors:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘T.Header Int’
Expected type: [T.Header Int]
  Actual type: [Int]
In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘leftcoll’
In the second argument of ‘T.Group’, namely
  ‘(map T.Header leftcoll)’


Couldn't match expected type ‘T.Header Text’
            with actual type ‘Text’
In the first argument of ‘T.Header’, namely ‘lbl’
In the expression: T.Header lbl
```

I have absolutely no clue why this is the case. From [the Table type documentation and example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tabular-0.2.2.7/docs/Text-Tabular.html#t:Table), it would appear that I simply have to apply the `Header` constructor to a list of values and then put them inside the `Group` constructor to get a whole row (or column) of values, but the errors there seem to suggest that the lists (and data) I'm passing as arguments to the `Header` constructor already need to be `Header`s. Thus, I'm confused about what the type system is telling me here, and how to get what I want.

Essentially, the table should look something like this:

```
Foo All Cluster0 Cluster1
=========================
1   10  3        7
2   11  10       1
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to find this one, because there is no problem in the definition of your function: it's the type declaration that is wrong.

Let's take a look at the definition of `Table`:

```
data Table rh ch a = Table (Header rh) (Header ch) [[a]]
```

The column header and row header type paramater are already warped in the `Header` type, so there no need to do it once more.

Instead of defining:

```
tabulate :: Text -> [[Int]] -> T.Table (T.Header Int) (T.Header Text) Int
```

you can defined:

```
tabulate :: Text -> [[Int]] -> T.Table Int Text Int
```

---

To debug that kind of things, I usually extract part of the expression to a where clause, along with a type annotation that tells the compiler what each the expression should be. This often gets me better error messages. For example, here, I extracted:

```
where tagada :: [T.Header Int]
      tagada = map T.Header leftcoll
```

In the error, I could read:

```
Expected type: [T.Header (T.Header Int)]
  Actual type: [T.Header Int]
```

That's when I realized that the `Header` type was maybe used twice.